# Spring hexadecimal String in properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have a hexidecimal value in a properties file and I want Spring to convert it to a byte array by using the @Value annotation in my java object.

Example:

```
hex.value=CB53CD20B2F222D9
```

And in java i have the following:

```
@Value("#{myProperties['hex.value'] ?: ''}")
private byte[] hexValue;
```

Spring currently just sets the String.getBytes() as hexValue but i want it to convert is to an actual byte array that represents the String. For example by using [Commons-Codec Hex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec//javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decode%28java.lang.Object%29)

Does anyone know how to configure Spring so that it doesn't just return the getBytes()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Types references](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#d0e11977) of Spring EL.

If you would like to use [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex#decodeHex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decodeHex%28char%5b%5d%29), so the target `@Value` will look the following:

```
@Value("#{T(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex).decodeHex((myProperties['hex.value'] == null ? '' : myProperties['hex.value'] ).toCharArray())}")
private byte[] hexValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The solution we tried was almost the same except for the T and brackets. Must have overlooked it in the SpEL documentation.

Comment: Devil's in the details, indeed